# Visual Studio 2010 Emacs Tab deletes characters

Tags: visual-studio-2010, auto-indent

In VS2008 with Emacs keybindings, hitting Tab would activate "auto indent", ie indenting the line correctly no matter where the cursor is. However, in VS 2010, it is still attempting to auto indent, but it is also erasing characters from the beginning of the line. So if I have a line like this (using | to represent cursor location):

```
 var i = 180.0|0;
```

after hitting tab, it looks like this:

```
0;
```

This is really frustrating behavior....